# What is the best proof of Stokes Theorem?

Tags: vector-analysis

I have seen several proofs of Stokes theorem; all of them involves heavy calculation and simplification of partial derivatives and computing cross products term by term.

The theorem is, however, extremely easy to understand intuitively. The total "circulation" around a curve $\gamma$ equals the sum of all "microscopic circulation" on a surface spanned by $\gamma$. For a diagram of "microscopic circulation", see [here.](https://mathinsight.org/greens_theorem_idea)

I hope I can find a proof which illustrates directly how the idea of summing over microscopic circulation. Algebraic simplification of partial derivatives doesn't seem to show this.

Comment: Stokes${}{}{}$!

Comment: Oh! The awful spell checker...

Comment: It's still Stokes!

Comment: This is going to be largely opinion-based: generally the "best" proof for anyone is the one they understand most intuitively.  (And it's Stokes's Theorem, or Stokes' Theorem if you prefer American orthography)

Comment: The proof in differential geometry is both more general and does not involve heavy calculations. Google provides pdf's.